# Inserting Node and arranging them in alphabetical order

Tags: c, string, pointers, linked-list, singly-linked-list

I have a song library where the user will input the songs and will be a linked list, however my insert into ordered list isn't working.

```
Node *insertIntoOrderedList(Node *head, char *songName, char *artist, char *genre) {
if (head == NULL || songName < head -> songName) {
    return newNode(songName, artist, genre, head); // a new head of the list
}
Node *current = head;

while (current -> link != NULL && songName <= current -> link -> songName)
    current = current -> link;

current -> link = newNode(songName, artist, genre, current -> link);
return head;
```

}

Right now when I print the linked list, it will be in the order of me inputting them, so if I enter B, A, C. It will be BAC instead of ABC when I print the list.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you are comparing pointers instead of to compare strings pointed to  by the pointers.

For example in this statement I think there should be

```
if (head == NULL || strcmp( songName, head -> songName ) < 0 ) {
```

instead of

```
if (head == NULL || songName < head -> songName) {
```

The same is valid for other statements where you are comparing pointers instead of the strings themselves.

That is you should use standard C function `strcmp` declared in header `<string.h>` to compare strings instead of pointers.

Also in this loop

```
while (current -> link != NULL && songName <= current -> link -> songName)
    current = current -> link;
```

the condition `songName <= current -> link -> songName` is wrong. The loop must to iterate while `current -> link -> songName` is less than or equal to  `songName`.

Thus it should look like

```
while (current -> link != NULL && strcmp( songName, current -> link -> songName ) >= 0 )
    current = current -> link;
```

Comment: when you say <0, this compares if the string is less than the other one, is this based on the length of string? like abc vs abcd or like the actual letters like 'apple' will come before 'cat' ?

Comment: @SoundSync If a smaller string is equal to a substring of the bigger string than it is less than the bigger string.

Comment: @SoundSync Each string is terminated by a zero character. And zero is always less than any other unsigned character. And strings are compared as unsigned character strings.

Comment: i'm testing my function and if i consectively input 4 letters such as a,b,c,d it prints out a,d,c,b. so it seems to push everything in reverse order. if I input an 'e' after, it will be a,e,d,c,b,